# Credentials for multiple AWS accounts on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am looking for a way to access AWS resources on multiple AWS accounts using AWS SDK (Java, probably irrelevant) running on an EC2 instance.

To be more precise, imagine there are two AWS accounts:

- test
- prod

There is a Java application running on an EC2 instance for **prod** account that creates for example an instance of AmazonEC2Client (from AWS Java SDK). I would like to be able to create the client instance for both **test** and **prod** accounts from there.

I am able to do this using profiles on local machine, but haven't figured out how to do this on EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways;

**AssumeRole**

Use the AWS Security Token Service to [AssumeRole](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html). The actual implementation would be up to you, but you can assign an [IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) to the EC2 Instance, and then use the AssumeRole function in the [Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.html) to switch from a production role to testing (or vice versa).

**Profiles**

It sounds like you've already figured out how to do this locally, but it could be replicated in EC2 (depending on the use case). That said, I would strongly advise against it and instead follow best practices and use STS:AssumeRole (above).

---

Realistically, it would probably be best (making some assumptions here about what you are actually trying to do) to have a separate EC2 instance for production and testing, in which case you can assign appropriate roles as needed.

Moreover, if we are talking about a larger deployment, you may want to explore [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html) which would let you isolate your production and testing environments completely by using separate AWS accounts for each (but a single billing account). To learn more about it, I would suggest taking a look at this article: https://blog.codeship.com/separate-aws-production-and-development-accounts/